# Can my PC run Unreal Engine with these specification?

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

My PC can run Unity 2020 LTS very well (multiple instances at the same time with multiple instances of VS 2022).

I am looking forward to installing Unreal Engine on my PC. Following are my PC specifications:

- Processor: AMD A8 5500b
- GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7560D
- Memory: 8 GB
- OS: Windows 8.1

I am using HDD and SSD isn't available. I want to install Unreal Engine 5. Will my PC handle it? Along With VS 2022. Or should I install Unreal Engine 4.26?

Comment: https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/hardware-and-software-specifications-for-unreal-engine/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended specifics for Unreal Engine 5 are:

- Processor: quad-core 2.5 GHz or
  faster. Your is a quad-core 3.2 GHz ✓
- GPU: DirectX 11 or 12 compatible graphics card. You GPU is compatible with DirectX 11 ✓
- Memory: 8GB like your ✓
- Operating system: Windows 10 64-bit version 1909 revision .1350 or higher, or versions 2004 and 20H2 revision .789 or higher. You better upgrade your Win8.1 (I suggest you to do it in any case, even without using Unreal Engine, since Win 10 is so much better) ;)

Source: [Unreal Engine 5 docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/hardware-and-software-specifications-for-unreal-engine/)